# Write specific class in hash with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My target is to change the hash of my URL with the class name of the pressed element.
The problem is: my element has 3 css classes, but I  only need one and only a part of it.

What I already have:

```
$(".container > section > header").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass("expand");
   window.location.hash = $(this).parent().attr('class');
});
```

The classname of the clicked element are: `about-c`, `stand-by` & `expand`. I only need the *about* of *about-c*. The *stand-by* and *expand* classes are on every element the same, only the *whatever-c* class is different (I only need to cut the `-c` part).

So how can I get only the `*-c`-class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

<kbd>**fiddle Demo**</kbd>

```
window.location.hash =/(\w+)-c/.exec($(this).parent().attr('class'))[1];
```

---

RegExp

```
/(\w+)-c/

Match the character “/” literally «/»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w+)»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the characters “-c/” literally «-c/»
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match the class attribute:

```
$(".container > section > header").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass("expand");
   window.location.hash = /(\w+)-c/.exec($(this).parent().attr('class'))[1];
});
```

To explain: This takes the string of your class attribute:

```
"about-c stand-by expand"
```

Matches it against the regex: `(\w+)-c` and selects the first group matched, which in this case will be `about`.

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QYWEY/2/) which demonstrates the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().attr('class').match(/\S+(?=-c\s|-c$)/)[0];
// \S+          : non-whitespace one or more times
// (?=-c\s|-c$) : followed by "-c" and a whitespace or the end of the string
```

This part `(?=-c\s|-c$)` prevents from matching strings like "about-cab".